# Grep is printing "grep:" - How to ignore it

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

I am looking to get port number in below filesunder directory `Variable`. When the file's port line is empty, I am getting `grep:` printed out. Is there a way to ignore it, and Print nothing?

```
if ls $directory/*.domain.*.properties 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    port=$(grep "domain.http.listener.port=" $directory/*.domain.*.properties | 
           awk -F "=" 'NR==1{print $NF}' | tr -d "\r")
fi
```

Comment: perhaps you should `grep` for your condition before assuming it's there?

Comment: Did you try redirecting standard error to /dev/null, like you are doing in your ls command?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) an example of your input file; ii) the output you want to get and iii) the output you are actually getting. We can't help you parse data you don't show us.

Comment: Jeff, Can you please share the example command, to grep the condition ?

Comment: Lewis, Yes I tried, It's sending everything there, and Giving me Zero Outputs

Comment: Terdon, I Only need to ignore the `grep:` from the output. I am getting 5 digit numbers as a port number. And the Variables are working fine. The files are there.

Comment: @Bek (please remember to use `@terdon` if you want to reply to me, I don't get notified otherwise) we really can't help if you don't show us what you are doing. You have chosen a very complex approach and if you simply [edit] your post and add your input file and your desired output, we can give you a much simpler solution. But without the input, we would have to guess and waste both your time and ours.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to look for the expression `domain.http.listener.port=` in multiple files with `grep`, and your `awk` command would print the last `=`-delimited field from the first line of that result (only), and then you delete any carriage return in the result of that.

The `ls` is not needed.  You seem to be using it to test whether the filename globbing pattern `$directory/*.domain.*.properties` matches anything (also possibly splitting the value of `$directory` on whitespace and performing filename globbing on those bits too).

To test whether a filename globbing pattern matches any filename, you may use

```
set -- "$directory"/*.domain.*.properties
```

(I've quoted the expansion of the `directory` variable because I assume it's supposed to contain the name or pathname of a single directory only) followed by

```
if [ "$#" -gt 1 ] || [ -e "$1" ]; then ...; fi
```

The `set` command sets the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.), and if we get more than one of these (`$#` is greater than 1), then the pattern matches more than one thing. Also if the pattern matched a single thing, we test the existence of that thing with `-e`.  That last test will distinguish between a single match and no match (the pattern remains unexpanded).

`awk` can do the work of `grep`, and of `tr`, so there really is no need for the pipeline that you have:

```
awk -F '=' '/domain\.http\.listener\.port=/ { sub("\r","", $NF); print $NF; exit }'
```

I'm escaping the dots in the regular expression as they would otherwise match any character.  I'm using only `sub()` here, rather than `gsub()`, as I assume you want to delete the carriage return at the end of the line and nowhere else.

All together:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- "$directory"/*.domain.*.properties

if [ "$#" -gt 1 ] || [ -f "$1" ]; then
    awk -F '=' '/domain\.http\.listener\.port=/ { sub("\r","", $NF); print $NF; exit }' "$@"
fi
```

I changed the `-e` test to a `-f` test as it makes more sense to run `awk` on a regular file (or a symbolic link to one), than on anything else (but I don't test the file types of any of the files if there are multiple matches).

The `"$@"` will expand to all the names (individually quoted) that pattern in the `set` command managed to match.

Would you want the pathname of the file that contained the first match, then you may modify the `awk` to something that also prints out the special variable `FILENAME` (e.g. `print FILENAME, $NF`).  Would you want *all* the matches (not just the first one in the first file), then remove the `exit`.

Note that this solution would fail if there are many hundreds or thousands of files matching the filename globbing pattern (as would yours).  In that case, you would do a shell loop instead:

```
for pathname in "$directory"/*.domain.*.properties; do
    if [ -f "$pathname" ]; then
        awk -F '=' '
            /domain\.http\.listener\.port=/ {
                sub("\r","", $NF); print $NF; found=1; exit
            }
            END { exit !found }' "$pathname" && break
    fi
done
```

Here I've opted to let `awk` exit with a zero exit status when the wanted text has been printed, which causes the loop to terminate.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed Knowledge. It's working fine, and getting what I need, But for some apps, it's not pulling up the Port number. Is there a way, to ignore the `grep:` output, so I can just add that, option to my original script, and get this done. Rather then completely going for another way? Thank you again. You are great.